# How to fix the messy vertices and edges?

Tags: vertices, edges, boolean-modifier

All my vertices and edges are messed up, but the faces are good enough in their positions. It happened after I did the boolean union and deleted the object that was no longer needed. Can anyone help me how to fix this?

[image]

[image]

Comment: There are times when it's quicker and easier to restart your model, using the previous attempt as a lesson and a  guide. This could be one of them.. the hint from the reference is that your model can be achieved without Booleans at all.

Answer (score 0):

Click on a vertex that you don't need in topology:

- Double tap <kbd>G</kbd> to slide
- Slide vertex to the nearest adjacent vertex
- Select vertices (or press <kbd>A</kbd> to select all vertices)
- Press <kbd>M</kbd> *> Merge By Distance* (or enable auto-merge when you're moving them).

You can also click on a vertex and press <kbd>X</kbd> *> Dissolve Vertices*

Comment: so, it would be one by one? How to enable auto-merge?

Comment: Yes. It will take some time. The best way to avoid mistakes like this is to duplicate and hide your model before your work with destructive modifiers. So when something bad happend, you can try again with clear topology. 

Automerge: go to edit mode. Press N to activate Sidebar -> Tool -> Options -> check Auto Merge Vertices 

https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/tools/tool_settings.html

Comment: It is very possible it will be way faster to just start over and model everything correctly from the start.